# How to remove default flex child margin?

Tags: css

I am trying to use "Row" & "Stack" and WordPress adds some class and "is-layout-flex" is one of them. It also adds a CSS where all the "is-layout-flex" child margin is set to 0. I don't want to overwrite it using "!important" for all the class that I am using in child.
So, is there any other way to remove that margin?
[image]